# in AS400, how do i go to the end of the source file ?

Tags: ibm-midrange

when i am using `STRDBG`, in the Display Module Source, how do I go to the end of the code ?

what I've done is using page down key, but in large source files this approach is awful.

Comment: Have you considered IBM's PC based IDE (complete with debugger) known as Rational Developer for i http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/dev-ibm-i .  Another option is the free java based Graphical Systemi5 debugger.  Both are discussed here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-debug/index.html

Comment: In Rational Developer for i [RDi] you would get to the end of the source the same as in most any PC editor, ctrl-end.  Once you've learned to debug in RDi (or do most anything for that matter) you probably wont want to go back to green screen.  It does more for you, with more flair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the ILE source debugger `top` and `bottom` on the "Debug . . ." command line will position appropriately.

See [Debug Commands](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzasc/sc092507264.htm) or the online help for more information.

Comment: Since it seems you are not familiar with the IBM i...it should be noted that online help is usually available by pressing the HELP key.  Assuming you're using a terminal emulator and not a actual 5250 terminal; most emulators have F1 configured to act as the HELP key.